# How to access one element in a object json array and bind this data on the X-axis in Ionic 6 / Chartjs?

Tags: android, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I following a tutorial how to use ChartJS in ionic 6. I have a json response like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",       
        "name": "Fruit",
        "last_updated": "2022-03-13T20:13:12.322Z"
    }
]
```

I only want to have the `"last_updated"` in my response and convert this to an array and bind it to the X-axis in a chart with the framework ChartJS.

This is my code to get the element and convert it to an array:

```
getLastUpdated() {
    var json;
    this.http.get(httpurl)
      .subscribe(data => {
        json = data;
        var datarray = [];
        for (var i of json.data) {
          datarray.push(i.last_updated)
          console.log(datarray);
        }

      })
  }
```

Then I call this method via a service like this:

`this.dataService.getLastUpdated();`

Bind this data like this:

```
lineChartMethod() {
    this.lineChart = new Chart(this.lineCanvas.nativeElement, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: dataarray,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Test',
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40, 10, 5, 50, 10, 15],

          }
        ]
      }
    });
  }
```

And in my HTML page I render the chart like this:

```
 <canvas #lineCanvas></canvas>
```

I get an error like this in my console:

ERROR TypeError: json.data is not iterable

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
for (var i of json.data) {
// ...

// Should become:

for (var i of json) {
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I see that I get response like this: `['2022-03-13T21:33:57.967Z']` how can I bind this to the chart?

Comment: @Fearcoder, I think you also need to fix the ID attribute in the HTML e,g: `<canvas id="lineCanvas">`. Possibly another error to fix is in your JS: `new Chart(this.lineCanvas, {...`